# A doubt about a delta estimation problem

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am able to solve these delta estimation problems, but I don't grasp the idea behind them. Here goes the problem:

We have $f(x)=x^2$ and $a=5$

Determine $\delta > 0$ where $ 0 < \left| x -(-5) \right| < \delta $, then $ \left| f(x)-25 \right| < \frac{1}{20} $

I know the process:

$$
\left| f(x)-25 \right| < \frac{1}{20} \\
\left| x^2-25 \right| < \frac{1}{20} \\
\left| x-5 \right|\left| x+5 \right| < \frac{1}{20} \\
$$
$$
\text{Then, we assume that } \delta_o=1 \\
\left| x+5 \right| < \delta_o=1 \\
-\delta_o <  x+5 < \delta_o \\
-1 < x+5  < 1 \\
-11 < x-5  < -9 \\
\text{Taking us to } \left| x-5 \right|<11 \\
$$
$$
\left| x-5 \right| \left| x+5 \right| \leq 11\left| x+5 \right| < \frac{1}{20} \\
\left| x+5 \right| < \frac{1}{220} \\
\text{Finally we get that $\delta$ needs to be the smaller number in the interval } (1, \frac{1}{220}) \text{ and $\delta = \frac{1}{220}$}  
$$

I get lost, in the interpretation, when we assume that delta is $1$ and its consequences. Why do we need to convert the expression in that block to the one we want to eliminate from the equation that needs to be satisfied? Why do we choose $11$, too? I was not shown the graphical representation for this problem, by the way.

Comment: Here is what I understand. We have a certain function. We want to find a delta that represents a distance less than the one between x and a constant, while we have the constraint that tells us that the distance between the function and another constant is less than 1/20. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that if $x$ is close enough to $5$, then $|x^2-25|\lt \frac{1}{20}$. Moreover, we want to be explicit about how close is close enough. We will get to a calculation like yours, but first let's be more simple-minded. We have
$$|x^2-25|\lt \frac{1}{20} \quad\text{if and only if} \quad 25-\frac{1}{20}\lt x^2\lt 25+\frac{1}{20}.$$ 
We are interested in positive $x$, in fact in $x$ near $5$. For such $x$, the inequality holds when 
$$\sqrt{25-\frac{1}{20}}\lt x\lt \sqrt{25+\frac{1}{20}}.$$
My calculator says this happens when 
$$4.9949975  x\lt 5.0049975.$$
So certainly if we choose for example $\delta=0.004$, then when $|x-5|\lt \delta$ we will have $|X^2-25|\lt \frac{1}{20}$.

---

Now we make an analysis closer to yours. The inequality $|x^2-25|\lt \frac{1}{20}$ can be rewritten as 
$$|x-5||x+5|\lt \frac{1}{20}.$$
Think of $x$ as being near $5$. Then $|x-5||x+5|$ is kind of small. The "spoiler" is the $|x+5|$ term, which could be sort of large.

We first make sure that $x$ is close to $5$ by asking, very modestly, that $x$ be between $4$ and $6$. That forces $x+5$ to be between $9$ and $11$. If $x+5$ is positive and less than $11$, then
$$|x-5||x+5|\lt 11|x-5|.$$
We can make the right-hand side less than $\frac{1}{20}$ by making $|x-5|\lt \frac{1}{(11)(20)}$. If we do that, then in particular the condition $4\lt 5\lt 6$ is satisfied.

The conclusion follows: If $|x-5|\lt \frac{1}{220}$, then $x^2-25|\lt \frac{1}{20}$.

**Remark:**  In this game, you do not need to find the *largest* $\delta$ such that if $|x-5|\lt \delta$, then our inequality holds. The problem only asked us to exhibit a $\delta$ that works.

Actually, $\frac{1}{220}$  does not give away much. It is not hard to see that if $x=5+\frac{1}{200}$, then $|x^2
=25|\gt \frac{1}{20}$.

Comment: Here: "If x is positive and less than 11", shouldn't that read "If x+5 is positive and less than 11"?

Comment: Thanks! You cleared it up! I think that my professor is new in the uni, plus he's not a native speaker. I would usually understand it, but he didn't even explain the "process".

Comment: @Fiire: Thanks for spotting it! Fixed. Yes, it is all about getting control over the size of things. There is manipulation involved, of course, but the basic idea is geometric.